# If the expectation tends to zero, show that $X_n \to X $ in probability.

Tags: probability

Show that if $\mathbb{E} |X_n - X| \to\ 0$ as $n \to\infty$, then $X_n \to\ X$ in probability. Furthermore, is the converse true?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** you can use the fact that, for any $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$
0 \leq \varepsilon\cdot \mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X - X_n\rvert \geq \varepsilon\} \leq \mathbb{E} \lvert X - X_n\rvert.
$$
(can you see why this is the case?)

As for the converse.... rule of thumb: if it were true, would we bother defining both convergence in probability *and* convergence in $L_1$ -- while they would be equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

The first statement follows from an application of Chabyshev-Markov's inequality
$P[|X_n-X|]>\varepsilon\leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon}E[|X_n-X|]$

For the second statement, consider the sequence

$X_n(t)=n^2\mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac1n]}(t)$ in the space $([0,1],\mathscr{B}([0,1]),\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue's measure. $X_n$ converges to $0$ pointwise a.s. and so in probability. However $X_n$ does not converge in mean to $0$.