# Example of convergence in probability, but expectation doesn't tend to 0

Tags: probability

I'm self teaching probability, and came across this thread:
[If the expectation tends to zero, show that $X_n \to X $ in probability.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473907/if-the-expectation-tends-to-zero-show-that-x-n-to-x-in-probability)

I understand that the converse is not true, but am struggling to think of a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the RVs $X_n$ where $\mathbb{P}(X_n = n) = 1/n$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 0) = 1-1/n$

Then $\mathbb{P}(|X_n -0|> \epsilon) = 1/n$ which goes to $0$ for big enough $n$ just fine.

But in $L1$/expectation we have that $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 1$ for all $n$.

Note that this fails convergence in $Lp$ for all $p$, not just $1$.